# Aks: Can we use Azure Dev Spaces to deploy Release build of Web app to Azure Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-2017, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

For hard core visual studio fans, it is not too friendly to run commands and wait for hours to deploy using Azure commands. I'm sure tooking would evolve, as of now:

> ```
> Can we use Azure Dev Spaces to deploy Release build of Web app to Azure Kubernetes?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Azure Dev Spaces to deploy your code to production, but not recommended. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/how-to/setup-cicd#dev-spaces-instrumentation-in-production